# how to wait for finish downloading a file and then read it

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I want to add ability to my app to download files from internet and then read some of them or extract them..Here Is my entire code

```
package co.tosca.persianpoem;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Download_database extends Activity {

    Download_db_list_Adapter dataAdapter = null;
    Download_db_list_Adapter Database_list_adapter = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> selected_items_for_download = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
    List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    persian_poem_class main=new persian_poem_class(this);
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> selected_databases = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    public ArrayList<String> downloaded_db_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> main_db_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Items_for_download = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = null;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_database);




        //T A B     H O S T
        TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.download_cat_tabhost);
        tabs.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("down_tag1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.download_cat_01);
        spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.txt_download_tab_download_sections));
        tabs.addTab(spec);
        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("down_tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.download_cat_02);
        spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.txt_download_tab_downloaded_db_list));
        tabs.addTab(spec);


        File path=new File(ClubCP.SDcardPath+"/temp/database/");
        List<String>file_lists =    main.directoryPath(path,false);

        downloaded_db_ids = main.directoryPath(path,true);
        main_db_ids=main.getDBPoet_id();




        //S P I N E R
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_cat_selector);
        String[] spineritems = { getString(R.string.radio_newgdb), getString(R.string.radio_programgdb), getString(R.string.radio_sitegdb)};
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spineritems);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> container, View row,
            int position, long id) {

            if(position==0){
                xmlp("newgdbs.xml");

            }
            else if(position==1){
                xmlp("programgdbs.xml");

            }
            else{
                xmlp("sitegdbs.xml");


            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> container) {
                Toast.makeText(Download_database.this, "At least select one database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });



        list=  (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ExpList);        


        //D A T A B A S E    L I S T    A D A P T E R

        Database_list_adapter=new Download_db_list_Adapter(this,R.layout.database_list_item, main.getDBonSDcard());
        ListView Database_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_db_list);
        Database_list.setAdapter(Database_list_adapter);






        // B U I L D    B U T T U N
        Button build =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_creat_db);
        build.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                selected_databases=Database_list_adapter.getSelectedItems();
                if(selected_databases.isEmpty()!=true){
                    new bulid_database().execute();

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Download_database.this, "At least select one database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });



        //  D O W N L O A D    B U T T U N
        Button download=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_download_db_start);
        download.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selected_items_for_download=dataAdapter.getSelectedItems();
                if(selected_items_for_download.size()!=0){
                    if(!isOnline()){

                        Toast.makeText(Download_database.this, "you are not connected to internet..Please check your connections", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
Log.i("execute download", "execute download");
                        new download_db().execute();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Download_database.this, "At least select one database", 1).show();
                }

            }
        });



        // H E L P    B U T T U N
        Button help=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_help);
        help.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String msg="<h1>"+getString(R.string.radio_newgdb)+"</h1>"+getString(R.string.txt_download_hint_newgdb)
                        +"<h1>"+getString(R.string.radio_programgdb)+"</h1>"+   getString(R.string.txt_download_hint_programgdb)
                        +"<h1>"+getString(R.string.radio_sitegdb)+"</h1>"+  getString(R.string.txt_download_hint_sitedb);
                    main.createDialogBox(Download_database.this,msg,getString(R.string.txt_information ),R.drawable.bullet_info ).show();

                }

            });



    }



    /**

    P U B L I C readfromAssets

    */
    public String readfromAssets(String name){
         xml=null;
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
      InputStream input;
      try {
     input = assetManager.open(name);

           int size = input.available();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
           input.read(buffer);
            input.close();

            // byte buffer into a string
              String text = new String(buffer);
     return text;
          } catch (IOException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
          }
    return null;
  }
    /**

    P U B L I C     V O I D  XMLP

    */
    private void xmlp(String xmlname){
        String xml = null ;
        if(isOnline()){
            new getxml().execute("http://ganjoor.sourceforge.net/"+xmlname);// getting XML new way

        }
        else{
            xml=readfromAssets(xmlname);
            Log.i("read from assets",xml);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cant find any network connection,Persian poem is loading from offline files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        menuItems.clear();
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(parser.KEY_gdb);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(parser.KEY_CatName, parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_CatName));
            map.put(parser.KEY_PoetID, parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_PoetID));
            map.put(parser.KEY_DownloadUrl, parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_DownloadUrl));
            map.put(parser.KEY_PubDate, parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_PubDate));
            String size = " ";
             try{
            long s= Long.parseLong(parser.getValue(e,parser.KEY_FileSizeInByte));
                 size=getText(R.string.txt_download_db_size)+" "+humanReadableByteCount( s,true);

             }
              catch (Exception e1) 
            {

                 Log.i("error", e1.getMessage());
            }

             map.put(parser.KEY_FileSizeInByte,size);
             String Status="0";
             String Poet_id=parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_PoetID);
             if(main.IsInlist(main_db_ids, Poet_id)){
                Status="1";
             }
             else if(downloaded_db_ids!=null&& main.IsInlist(downloaded_db_ids, Poet_id)){
                Status="2";
             }



             map.put("Status",Status);
             menuItems.add(map);

        }


        dataAdapter = new Download_db_list_Adapter(this,R.layout.database_list_item, menuItems);
        list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    }

    public class getxml extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
             xml=null;
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("getxml", xml);
            return xml;
        }

    }
    public class download_db extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS=100/selected_items_for_download.size();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Download_database.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...items) {
            if(isDownloadManagerAvailable(Download_database.this)){
             for(int i=0;i<selected_items_for_download.size();i++){
                    HashMap<String, String> item =selected_items_for_download.get(i);
                    String[] progress={String.valueOf(i+1),item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID)};
                    Log.i("download_manager", "download file"+progress);
                    download_file(item.get(parser.KEY_DownloadUrl),item.get(parser.KEY_CatName),"Downloading file,Please wait...",item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID));
                    Log.i("download_manager", "startextracting file");
                  //  publishProgress(progress);
                    unpackZip(ClubCP.SDcardPath+"/temp/database/",item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID)+ ".zip");
                    }
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String...progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC","progress update");
             mProgressDialog.setMessage("Extracting "+progress[1]+"...");
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)*Integer.valueOf(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
        }
    }

     /**
      * @param context used to check the device version and DownloadManager information
      * @return true if the download manager is available
      */
     public static boolean isDownloadManagerAvailable(Context context) {
         try {
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                 return false;
             }
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
             intent.setClassName("com.android.providers.downloads.ui", "com.android.providers.downloads.ui.DownloadList");
             List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
                     PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
             return list.size() > 0;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     public void download_file(String download_link,String filename,String discribtion,String poet_id){
         String url = download_link;
         DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
         request.setDescription(discribtion);
         request.setTitle(filename);
         // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
             request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
             request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
         }
         request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(ClubCP.SDcardPath+"/temp/database/", poet_id+".zip");

         // get download service and enqueue file
         DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
         manager.enqueue(request);

     }



     private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
     {       
          InputStream is;
          ZipInputStream zis;
          try 
          {
              String filename;
              is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
              zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
              ZipEntry ze;
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int count;

              while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
              {
                  // zapis do souboru
                  filename = ze.getName();

                  // Need to create directories if not exists, or
                  // it will generate an Exception...
                  if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                     File fmd = new File(path + filename);
                     fmd.mkdirs();
                     continue;
                  }

                  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

                  // cteni zipu a zapis
                  while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                  {
                      fout.write(buffer, 0, count);             
                  }

                  fout.close();               
                  zis.closeEntry();
              }

              zis.close();
          } 
          catch(IOException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return false;
          }

         return true;
     }

        private class bulid_database extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Void> {

            // Begin - can use UI thread here
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                  pd = ProgressDialog.show(Download_database.this,"","Please wait...", true,false);
            }
            // this is the SLOW background thread taking care of heavy tasks
            // cannot directly change UI
            protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
                // simulate here the slow activity
                main.emptyDB();
                main.creatDB(8);
                for (int i =0; i < selected_databases.size(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> Database=selected_databases.get(i);

                    main.attachDatabase(Database.get("CatName"));
                    //publishProgress((long)i);
                }
                    return null;
                    }
            // periodic updates - it is OK to change UI
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... value) {
                pd.setMessage("still working");
            }
            // End - can use UI thread here
            protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
                if (pd!=null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    }
            }
            }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.download_database, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }
}
```

As you see when activity starts I checkd internet connection and then I try to download a file from Internet and then read that file..How do I make sure that file is downloaded and then I try to read it?here Is pice of code that I used to download and read file

```
    private void xmlp(String xmlname){
    String xml = null ;
    if(isOnline()){
        new getxml().execute("http://ganjoor.sourceforge.net/"+xmlname);// getting XML new way

    }
    else{
        xml=readfromAssets(xmlname);
        Log.i("read from assets",xml);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant find any network connection,Persian poem is loading from offline files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


and here is getxml() function
    public class getxml extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
             xml=null;
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("getxml", xml);
            return xml;
        }

    }
```

My question Is do above method guarantee calling after download file?or It will continue while downloading a file with empty xml?because when I run app I get null exeption error

```
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.XMLParser.getDomElement(XMLParser.java:113)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database.xmlp(Download_database.java:264)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database.access$3(Download_database.java:251)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database$1.onItemSelected(Download_database.java:118)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:848)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 09:44:50.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 09:45:31.374: W/dalvikvm(14083): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
```

and on line 264 I have this `Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element` that I think Its because an empty xml file (or file Is still downloading)..
I have this kind of problem In another place..I want to doanload a zip file and then I exteact It..I tried a AsyncTask Its here

```
public class download_db extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS=100/selected_items_for_download.size();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Download_database.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...items) {
    if(isDownloadManagerAvailable(Download_database.this)){
     for(int i=0;i<selected_items_for_download.size();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> item =selected_items_for_download.get(i);
            String[] progress={String.valueOf(i+1),item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID)};
            Log.i("download_manager", "download file"+progress);
            download_file(item.get(parser.KEY_DownloadUrl),item.get(parser.KEY_CatName),"Downloading file,Please wait...",item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID));
            Log.i("download_manager", "startextracting file");
          //  publishProgress(progress);
            unpackZip(ClubCP.SDcardPath+"/temp/database/",item.get(parser.KEY_PoetID)+ ".zip");
            }
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String...progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC","progress update");
     mProgressDialog.setMessage("Extracting "+progress[1]+"...");
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)*Integer.valueOf(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

    if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

}

Here again I want to make sure `unpackZip` runs after finishing download file..How to make this?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Majid its Huge coding,you can take your downloading code apart your main codes.so it's more easy to read .you can check your response entity in do in background and check your unpacking process to find out is it compelete or not.

Comment: @Arash Thanks for your help,Actully I am new with programing I just want to try to make sure It works and then I wanted to optimize code :D But Thanks for your advise ..So If I want to this for several files does It works?Because I want to do unpacking in background too and I think It will make user confuse when saw a lot of prosess dialogs:(

Comment: it absoloutly works on sevral files,if you have multiple AsyncTask Classes, you can call next class on OnpostExecute function of your first class(with this code : new NextAsyncTaskClass(ActivityContext).execute();).also you can unpack on background code.remember that you can't just modify your UI on DoinBackground.

Comment: Thanks dear friend..I have one more question..In a asynctast all other commands will wait for finish my task?For example If I want to read a file after downloading ..It will guarantee to read It after finish downloading?

Comment: yes it waits until your download completes (it runs line by line), but always you should be aware of checking Null Response because of downloading problems such as destination unreachable and so on(catching Exceptions).hope it helped you.Good Luck

Comment: Yes It was grate Again.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much code to go though. I assume you are downloading the file in your `doInBackground()` method. Then you can make sure that `unpackZip` is called by invoking it from  `onPostExecute()` method.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...items) {
   // download your file here
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

    //do your unpackZip here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem that I want to repeat this task for several files..I think whit this method I cant do It for each file..right?

Comment: you can try creating multiple asynctask's. But best way would be to try and create a service which handles your downloads asynchronoulsy.

Comment: Can I use multipe asynctasks with a single dialog?I dont want to make users confuse by showing many dialogs..I just want to make sure call a task just after finishing previos task not In the same time..For example download xml file and then read It..Not try to read file while file Is not downloaded yet